# How to remove multiple characters in a string in excel

Tags: excel, vba, data-cleaning

I have a few thousand rows I would like to clean. I would like to remove all repeated commas and replace them with just one comma. I am using excel. Examples can be scene below

| Current Data | Desired Output |
| --- | --- |
| ,,,,,,,,,, |  |
| one,,,,,,two,,,,,three | one, two, three |
| two,,,,one,,,,,, | two, one |
| two,,, one,one,two,,,one | two, one, one, two, one |

Comment: Try the substitute() function.

Comment: One way is to convert text to columns, delimited by comma. Then save as csv file. Your data are now clean with just one comma between values. If you have other columns, then this option is not optimal. Another option is to do find/replace... find 2 commas and replace with 1, find 3 and replace with 1, and so on. If you only have 10 or so variations, then this is quick.

Comment: RegExp is a usefull tool.

Comment: `Do While Instr(txt, ",,")>0: txt = Replace(txt, ",,", ","): Loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply it to a cell as a user-defined function, and if you have a lot of data, it will be faster to use a procedure.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vResult() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim str As String
    
    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vResult(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        str = vDB(i, 1)
        vResult(i, 1) = myresult(str)
    Next i
    Range("b1").Resize(r) = vResult
End Sub

Function myresult(str As String)
    Dim vR(), vS, v
    Dim n  As Integer
    vS = Split(str, ",")
     For Each v In vS
        If v <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = v
        End If
    Next v
    If n Then
       myresult = Join(vR, ", ")
    Else
        myresult = ""
    End If
End Function
```

[image]